# Centos VMWare backup emergency mode password reset

Tags: centos, boot, root

I have recently backed up my remote virtual machine and downloaded the data into my local. I did the setup on my local with VMware workstation and tried starting the server. I realized I missed copying the 2nd drive so while it is still downloading the 2nd drive I tried to remove the reference on the VMware config for now and started the VM again.

This time it got through but I can't login with my password. So I tried to start it with `single` for single user mode (bypass password). But it is still asking me, here is a screenshot:

[image]

If I try to `continue (ctrl+D)` instead I get this looping prompt for password:

[image]

What could be wrong, and how can I log in now? Is the problem because I removed the 2nd drive? Should I just add it back in (when the download is completed). Would everything go back to normal after and allow me to use the single user mode to reset my password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start another Linux VM, and mount that disk to repair the problem.

In addition, to avoid the password entered in single user mode, change as follows /lib/systemd/system/rescue.service.

```
--- /lib/systemd/system/rescue.service.orig     2015-11-20 13:49:03.000000000 +0900
+++ /lib/systemd/system/rescue.service  2016-04-11 15:58:31.002000000 +0900
@@ -18,11 +18,11 @@
 WorkingDirectory=/root
 ExecStartPre=-/bin/plymouth quit
 ExecStartPre=-/bin/echo -e 'Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view\\nsystem logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to\\nboot into default mode.'
-ExecStart=-/bin/sh -c "/usr/sbin/sulogin; /usr/bin/systemctl --fail --no-block default"
+ExecStart=-/bin/bash
 Type=idle
 StandardInput=tty-force
-StandardOutput=inherit
-StandardError=inherit
+StandardOutput=tty
+StandardError=tty
 KillMode=process
 IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
 SendSIGHUP=yes
```

Comment: Be looking into this tonight. Thanks. Upvoted for the script provided.